# convergence of an infinite product (how to prove ?)

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

Fix $C > 0 $ a constant and fix $n \in N$. Consider $\alpha \in (0,1)$ fixed.

I am reading a paper and the authors says:

For an arbitrary $r <1$ , the infinite product
$$P = \prod_{j=0}^{\infty} (1+C 2^{n/2}(2^{-j}r)^{\alpha / 2})$$
always converges.
How can I prove this?  I dont know how to start. Someone can give me a help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd try to show the absolute value of product function eventually is equal to or less than 1. So take the limit as j goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The [standard result for infinite products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria) is that, provided no $p_n=-1$,
$$ \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+p_n) $$
converges if and only if
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |p_n| $$
does. In this case, you have
$$ p_n = C 2^{n/2} (2^{-j}r)^{\alpha/2}, $$
on which you can use the ratio test to check the sum converges.